# Datamapper in Code Igniter deals with a relationship as many to many

Tags: codeigniter, datamapper

I have a very confusing problem..

I configured data mapper and started to use it with code igniter.. I have this class:

```
class FamilyMemberDetail extends DataMapper {
var $table = "family_members_details";
var $has_one = array('gender', 'maritalstate');

public function __toString() {
    return is_string($this->id) ? $this->id : "";
}

}
```

For gender it is working fine..

```
class Gender extends DataMapper {
var $table = "genders";
var $has_many = array("familymemberdetail");

public function __toString() {
    return is_string($this->gender_label) ? $this->gender_label : "";
}

}
```

But with marital status:

```
class MaritalState extends DataMapper {
var $table = "marital_state";
var $has_many = array("familymemberdetail");

public function __toString() {
    return is_string($this->marital_state_label) ? $this->marital_state_label : "";
}

}
```

I get this error!

```
Error Number: 1146

Table 'elkhoudary_family.kh_family_members_details_marital_state' doesn't exist

SELECT `kh_marital_state`.* FROM (`kh_marital_state`) LEFT OUTER JOIN `kh_family_members_details_marital_state` kh_family_members_details_marital_state ON `kh_marital_state`.`id` = `kh_family_members_details_marital_state`.`maritalstate_id` WHERE `kh_family_members_details_marital_state`.`familymemberdetail_id` = 1

Filename: C:\AppServ\www\elkhoudary\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

The problem is that I didn't specify this relationship to need a join table and yet.. CI insists that it needs a table in between.. isn't it supposed to work like gender.. what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out why and it is really stupid.. the relation column should be named [className]_id not [tableName]_id and since I have my class named "MaritalState" and my table name "marital_state".

So I changed all entities to '_'s instead of Camel cases and everything went fine..

```
class Family_member_detail extends DataMapper {
var $table = "family_members_details";
var $has_one = array('gender', 'marital_state');

public function __toString() {
    return is_string($this->id) ? $this->id : "";
}

}
```

Gender:

```
class Gender extends DataMapper {
var $table = "genders";
var $has_many = array("family_member_detail");

public function __toString() {
    return is_string($this->gender_label) ? $this->gender_label : "";
}

}
```

Marital State:

```
class Marital_state extends DataMapper {
var $table = "marital_state";
var $has_many = array("family_member_detail");

public function __toString() {
    return is_string($this->marital_state_label) ? $this->marital_state_label : "";
}
}
```